# Is there an efficient way to loop through this problem?

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, combinations

So I saw this very interesting problem. Let's say you have a length of 2, and a base length of 5

`l = 2, b = 5`

this would be translated to :

```
11000
```

Now if you give an input let's say a **2** the ones on the problem above should move by this number. :

```
11000 → input 2 : 10100
```

So the pattern is like this :

```
input: 1 → 11000
input: 2 → 10100
input: 3 → 10010
input: 4 → 10001
input: 5 → 01100
input: 6 → 01010
input: 7 → 01001
input: 8 → 00110
input: 9 → 00101
input: 10 → 00011

input = 10 would be the final number
```

So the problem is what if you have an **l** equals to `8` and **b** equals to `50` :

```
11111111000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

And you're looking for a pattern something like :

```
00000010000000011000000000010010000000110000000010
```

How would this problem be solved without an absurdly large number, is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problematic is related to the [Combinatorial number system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_number_system).

If your are looking for the index corresponding to the pattern "00000010000000011000000000010010000000110000000010":

- determine the positions of the 1's in this pattern, from right to left (0 corresponding to the rightmost position):
- we have: $c_1=1, c_2=10, c_3=11, c_4=19, c_5=22, c_6=33, c_7=34, c_8=43$,
- the corresponding index is: $\binom{50}{8} - \sum_{k=1}^6\binom{c_k}{k} = 385352532$,
- note that $\binom{50}{8}$ is the number of 01-strings of length 50 with 8 1's.